# Ulimits and pam modules

Tags: linux, ubuntu, security, pam, ulimit

Can you explain me the relation of ulimit setting on a proccess and line

`session required pam_limits.so`

in pam module. In wich modules i really require this line?

I have this line in 
`pam.d/su`
`pam.d/sudo`
Do I require it in `common-session` as suggested this post for example:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/162229/how-do-i-increase-the-open-files-limit-for-a-non-root-user.

And why do I require it if i do ? )

And one more question: 
if i have

```
root            soft    nofile  8192
root            hard    nofile  8192
```

in `/etc/security/limits.conf` it automatically  forbids setting all nofile ulimits for other users that wants more open files  than `8192` and are allowed to do this by file in `/etc/security/limits.d/` directory ?

Why does this happen ?

If i don't have directives in `/etc/security/limits.conf` and spawn a program in a shell that drop's it's privileges everything is right: process has `nofile 65535` files open. But if i add

```
root            soft    nofile  8192
root            hard    nofile  8192
```

why the process can't grab it's own limits? I know that the process should inherits all limits from parent, but why in this case it is possible for a process to get higher privileges, than defaults of `root` when no `root` has no explicitly limited in  `/etc/security/limits.conf` ?